# Fourier Transform of Even/Odd Complex Functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, even-and-odd-functions

For any complex-valued $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, let's define its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ with the following convention
$$
\hat{f}(\omega) := \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-i \omega x} dx
$$

I would like a confirmation of the following:

- $f$ even $\Rightarrow$ $\hat{f}$ even
- $f$ odd  $\Rightarrow$ $\hat{f}$ odd

To prove for example the first statement, I would argue that
$$
\hat{f}(\omega)
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-i \omega x} dx
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(-x) e^{i \omega x} dx
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)  e^{i \omega x} dx
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)  e^{-i (-\omega) x} dx
= \hat{f}(-\omega)
$$
where the second equality is a consequence of the fact that the Lebesgue measure ($\lambda$) satisfies  $\lambda(A) = \lambda(-A)$, for every Borel set $A$ and the third is just using the hypothesis, i.e. that $f(x) = f(-x)$.

The second statement can be proved in the very same way.

Is the above correct?!?

I started having second thoguhts after seeing this heavily downvoted answer
[Fourier transform of even/odd function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184332/fourier-transform-of-even-odd-function/2381973#2381973)
and especially its first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The corresponding parity of the Fourier transform follows from the parity of the function and the fact that the Lebesgue integral is invariant under reflection (which follows from the relative invariance of Lebesgue measure).

Comment: Thanks - I was a bit confused by that comment and by the fact that the Wiki article on the Fourier transform https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform does not explicitly mention this fact.